# Programatically open a menu from menubar(Simulate the menu click programmatically for UI automation test)

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

`MenuManager` and `MenuContribution` items has been already created.

For the input `Menu` Item id/label, I need to problematically drop-down/open/display a `menu` item from `menubar` in `Eclipse`. I think I may need to fire some event.

This is requirement for UI Automation that `Menu` should be drop down automatically.

Can you please help at the earliest. I'm trying following, but here not sure how to set the x & y co-ordinates where `mouse click event` should be fired.

Code:

```
String toCompare = "File";
Menu menu = window.getShell().getMenuBar();
if(menu!=null && !menu.isDisposed()){
    MenuItem[] items = menu.getItems();
    for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++){
        String menuText = LegacyActionTools.removeMnemonics(items[i].getText());
        if(toCompare.equalsIgnoreCase(menuText)){
            Event event = new Event();
            event.doit = true;

            event.widget = items[i];
            event.type = SWT.MouseDown;
            event.button = 1;

            boolean success = items[i].getDisplay().post(event);
            System.out.println("Could we generate the event ? "+success);
        }                       
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) for UI automation?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use dedicated tools for UI testing, such as [SWTBot](http://eclipse.org/swtbot/). It seems typicall matche what you would do